# Wavefunction of three particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

(A)

Consider a quantum-mechanical system :  3 particles in a rigid sphere.

Which of the following is the correct form of wavefunction for this system ?

(a) $\psi(r_1,r_2,r_3,t) = \psi_1(r_1,t) . \psi_2(r_2,t).\psi_3(r_3,t)$

(b) $\psi(r_1,r_2,r_3,t) = \psi_1(r_1,t) + \psi_2(r_2,t) + \psi_3(r_3,t) $

where $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are position vectors of the three particles and $t$ is the time.

If one is correct, then what is wrong with the other?

Also what is justification for the right form - experimental / theoretical ?

(B)
Even though I am giving example of 3-particle system above, still I want to ask this :
In Schrodinger equation, can $\psi$ refer to more than one particle?

If I am not wrong, Schrodinger himself derived his equation for a single particle only from making changes in "Hamilton-Jacobi equation for a single particle".

Here I am **NOT** referring to usual explanation given in textbooks - that either repeat the experiment with single particle OR do single experiment with ensemble of particles, prepared in the same state.

Comment: A wave function describing several particles are once is standard fare in quantum many-body physics, which branches into, and becomes the foundation for, quantum chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

A generic wavefunction for a 3-particle system doesn't have to take any specific form; it is simply a function $\psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2,\mathbf r_3)$ such that $\int \mathrm d^3r_1 \mathrm d^3 r_2 \mathrm d^3 r_3 |\psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2,\mathbf r_3)|^2 < \infty$.  In particular, there's no reason it should need to "factor." A wavefunction which *does* factor into the form $\psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2,\mathbf r_3)=\psi_1(\mathbf r_1)\psi_2(\mathbf r_2)\psi_3(\mathbf r_3)$ is called *separable*.

With that said, if $\{\phi_i\}$ is a basis for the single-particle Hilbert space $\mathscr H$, then any wavefunction in the 3-particle Hilbert space $\mathscr H\otimes\mathscr H \otimes \mathscr H$ can be written in the form

$$\psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2,\mathbf r_3) = \sum_{ijk} c_{ijk} \phi_i(\mathbf r_1)\phi_j(\mathbf r_2)\phi_k(\mathbf r_3)$$
for some constants $c_{ijk}$. That is, the wavefunction need not be separable, but it can be written as a linear combination of terms which are. As a result, both of your proposed wavefunctions are permissible! The first one is immediately separable, and the second can be written

$$\psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2,\mathbf r_3) = \psi_1(\mathbf r_1)\mathbf 1(\mathbf r_2)\mathbf 1(\mathbf r_3) + \mathbf 1(\mathbf r_1) \psi_2(\mathbf r_2) \mathbf 1(\mathbf r_3) + \mathbf 1(\mathbf r_1)\mathbf 1(\mathbf r_2) \psi_3(\mathbf r_3) $$
$$= \psi_1(\mathbf r_1)+\psi_2(\mathbf r_2)+\psi_3(\mathbf r_3)$$
where $\mathbf 1(\mathbf r) = 1$ inside the sphere.

Note that this applies to *distinguishable* particles. If the particles in the system are indistinguishable fermions or bosons, then you need to apply extra symmetry constraints which make the 3-particle wavefunction either antisymmetric or symmetric respectively, and this further constrains the form that wavefunctions may have. For example, a simple product $\psi_1(\mathbf r_1)\psi_2(\mathbf r_2)\psi_3(\mathbf r_3)$ is not permitted for a system of fermions.

Comment: ...You already assumed addition in the equation immediate below the equation containing summation symbol.

Comment: @atom I'm not sure what you mean by that. My intention was to demonstrate that $\psi_1(\mathbf r_1)+\psi_2(\mathbf r_2)+\psi_3(\mathbf r_3)$ is the sum of three separable terms and is therefore an allowed 3-particle wavefunction.

Comment: "sum of separable terms" ....... I meant to say you started from taking the sum already...introduction of 1(r) =1 is not clear at all

Comment: @atom Sorry, I still don't understand the problem. There's nothing to *derive* here - the **definition** of the three-particle Hilbert space is essentially the space of wavefunctions which can be written as a linear combination of separable terms.  I used the notation $\mathbf 1(\mathbf r)$ to emphasize that each term in the sum $\psi_1(\mathbf r_1) + \ldots$ can be understood as the product of three single-particle wavefunctions.

Comment: @atom If I'm understanding you correctly, you are asking for proof that adding separable wavefunctions together is allowed, but that's part of the *definition* of the tensor product space $\mathscr H \otimes \mathscr H \otimes \mathscr H$.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider probability of particle $1$ being at point $x_1$, particle $2$ at point $x_2$ and particle $3$ at point $x_3$, we need to multiply the corresponding one particle probabilities (the word *and* is telling here, as opposed to *or* when the probabilities are summed):
$$
\rho(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)=\rho_1(x_1,t)\rho_2(x_2,t)\rho_3(x_3,t) = |\psi_1(x_1,t)|^2|\psi_2(x_2,t)|^2|\psi_3(x_3,t)|^2=\\|\psi_1(x_1,t)\psi_2(x_2,t)\psi_3(x_3,t)|^2=|\psi(x_1,x_1,x_3,t)|^2.
$$
So the answer is $$\psi(x_1,x_1,x_3,t)=\psi_1(x_1,t)\psi_1(x_2,t)\psi_1(x_3,t).$$

This is hwoever only a part of the story, as we also need to take into account the particle statistics/indistinguishability (as expressed by the famous Pauli exclusion principle for fermions). This is done with the help of Slater determinant (or [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) for bosons):
$$
\psi(x_1, x_2, x_3) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3!}}
\left|\begin{matrix}
\psi_1(x_1) & \psi_2(x_1) & \psi_3(x_1)\\
\psi_1(x_2) & \psi_2(x_2) & \psi_3(x_2)\\
\psi_1(x_3) & \psi_2(x_3) & \psi_3(x_3)\\
\end{matrix}\right| = ...
$$

Comment: Why do you assume that each particle is in the same 1-particle state $\psi$?

Comment: @J.Murray a typo. Thanks.